# Apache Camel - onWhen() predicate cannot retrieve EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, but in the processor it is present

Tags: java, apache-camel

I cannot access caught exception in `onWhen(predicate)` after `doCatch()`, but I can see it in the processor in `doCatch()`. This is inconvenient when I want to define a finer-grained predicate in `onWhen()`.

```java
doCatch(ProcessingException.class).onWhen(predicate) // <<< here I cannot see exception
    .process(MyProcessor.class) // <<< here I see exception
    ...
```

`exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class)` returns null in the predicate. I see `exchange.getAllProperties()` does not contain the key.

Any idea? Is it by design? Now I cannot decide enter catch processor or not depending on exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with this until I read the method's documentation:

> Sets an additional predicate that should be true before the onException is triggered.
>
> To be used for fine grained controlling whether a thrown exception should be intercepted by this exception typeor not.

That may explain why you are able to see the exception details in the processor and not in the "onWhen" clause.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: I read that and am still confused. When `onException` triggers, does it proceed to `doCatch` or not? Is `onWhen` happening at the same time as `doCatch`, or before, or?

Comment: As I understand it, the `onWhen` clause is calculated even before the `onException` is triggered. That is why you cannot use any exception property in the `onWhen` clause.

Then, if the `onWhen` and the `onException` conditions are met, the `doCatch` block triggers.

Comment: Thanks. I pay attention a lot on the order of words and if the syntax of Camel put `onException().onWhen()` but actually it's like `onWhen() -> exception -> onException() -> doCatch()`, for me it's confusing, unbearable and impossible to comprehend. Thanks bro.